# Assign a regular expression a variable name and use it in another regular expression

Tags: flex-lexer, lex

So in flex, I'm trying to assign these:

```
ID     letterletter*
NUM    digitdigit*
letter [a-zA-Z]
digit  [0-9]
```

But flex is telling me that the ID and NUM are unrecognized rules. One way to bypass this would be setting ID to `[0-9][0-9]*`, but I want to use letter and digit.

Is this be possible?

Comment: Why do you want to use `letter` and `digit`? Why not just use the builtin character classes `[[:alpha:]]`, `[[:digit:]]` and `[[:alnum:]]`? That's also more precise than character ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ID     {letter}{letter}*
NUM    {digit}{digit}*
letter [a-zA-Z]
digit  [0-9]
```

The same goes for ID and NUM, anywhere you use them.

Comment: Okay that was pretty simple. I tried using () but that didn't work. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do such thing, it's unnecessary. You can recurse pattern wrapped in a group, like this: `([a-zA-Z])(?1)`. `(?1)` repeats first pattern and matches `qw`, `er`, `ty` in `qwerty`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Rp5r8G/1)

So instead of trying to "build" your pattern from repeating parts, you can use recursive calls.

Comment: That's also another cool way to do it, but when I tried it a bunch of errors popped up. I'd rather be safe and just use https://stackoverflow.com/users/5885523/judismar-arpini-junior 's solution, which is what I was looking for. Thanks though, just learned something new from you too!

Comment: @PiguFilms I am glad to hear that :) Don't forget to accept his answer if it was solution (green check mark on the left).

Comment: This regex syntax is not accepted by [tag:flex-lexer]. When answering questions with this tag, please take into account the nature of (f)lex patterns, documented [here](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/)

Comment: @rici Thanks for comment, but I have read that it uses PCRE regex engine, which accepts such syntax.

Comment: You are probably thinking about Adobe Flex, which is a totally different thing. The flex scanner generator compiles regular expressions into code using its own regex syntax.